# How to set the screen orientation to Landscape mode in a activity when the auto rotation feature is turned off in the device settings in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

Well, I have a requirement, where the orientation of the screen should be changed, when the phone is turned even when the auto-rotation feature is off on the android-device settings.

I know this can be achieved by using the

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

in the onCreate of the Activity.

or by

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
}
```

Any tips or best practices or code snippets that can achieve this? Is this way of implemenatation right? Also it would be helpful if someone has managed to achieve it within custom views or fragments to share the logic on how it could be implemented.
Thanks for the help!

I know it can be done in the AndroidManifest file by adding a tag, but that would always limit the layout to be in landscape and this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: simply add screen orientation to landscape in your manifest activity tag for that activity.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please correct it for better understanding

Comment: Updated it.. hope it is clearer now.